# How to add OnBackPressed in webVeiw in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I am trying to add OnBackPressed in webVeiw but it is giving error
MainActivity.kt -

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack()}
     else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

All the other things are working fine but after adding this this is not working please if anyone have any solution please give

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @KenWolf the error is E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process

Comment: and kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property webView has not been initialized

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access webView before you initialise it

Comment: even when i've added lateinit var webView: WebView

Comment: That does not initialise it. You are missing `findViewById` (or similar) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View. In fact `lateinit` specifically is saying "I'll initialise it later" https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#late-initialized-properties-and-variables

Comment: the webView and onBackPressed() are working fine but when using it for privacy policy it closes the app as there is no backstack of webview  i want to come to my last page in the app from where i jumped to webView How to do that @KenWolf